# Android OnBoarding with ViewPager and different numbers of Buttons?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, baseadapter

I want to create something like OnBoarding app to swipe over the different views. Currently I have one view with several sections (Header + Buttons) with several buttons per section on a ScrallView. I want to divide the section so that I can slide back and fourth through the different sections resp. one section -> one view or fragment.

to make the question more specific, do I have to initialize the ArrayAdapter for my buttons in the

```
 @Override
 public void onPageSelected(int position) {}
```

Method from the PageViewer ??

**Update**
[Scrallview with several section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OohPv.png)

Comment: Can you share the screen

Comment: a FragmentPageAdapter with one Fragment-class and several fragment-layouts .... is that the right approach?